# MS Access Error 2105 "You can't go to the specified record" after adding new fields

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access database that I maintain that tracks user daily production with a form and continuous subform. Each record in the continuous subform tracks the information from a production order that the user completes - parts, quantity, etc.

Due to some overloading of the tablets that they're currently used on, I tried adding more fields to the backend tables to keep fields from holding "temporary" information. Since then, the function that I use to calculate task time has not been working and I can't figure out why.

Every time you click to calculate it gives the error 2105 when it tries to move to the second record. This is a piece of code that I've used in several other databases with no issue and previously worked up until I added the new fields. These were fields that were previously temporary but are now stored as data.

The code below shows the iteration process that it uses to check. It goes through the fields of each subform before moving to the next record, checking to see if controls with information in the tag field are empty or not. As far as I'm aware, nothing is different about the newly added fields in the Property Sheet. I retried an older version of this database file and found no problems running this calculation with the new fields.

```
If Me.NewRecord = 0 Then

    DoCmd.GoToControl "Record_Subform"
    subform_count = Forms!Record![Record_Subform].Form.RecordsetClone.RecordCount

    For x = 1 To subform_count
        Me.Record_Subform.SetFocus
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acGoTo, x

        For Each ctl In Forms!Record![Record_Subform].Form.Controls

            If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Then
                If ctl.Tag <> "" Then
                MsgBox (ctl)
                    If IsNull(ctl.Value) = True Or Len(ctl.Value) = 0 Then
                        msg1_bool = True
                        i = i + 1
                        ReDim Preserve field_array(i - 1)
                        field_array(i - 1) = ctl.Tag
                    End If
                End If
            End If

        Next ctl

        If IsNull(Me!Record_Subform.Form!Suspension_PN) = True And Me!Record_Subform.Form!NoSuspension.Value = False Then
            msg1_bool = True
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve field_array(i - 1)
            field_array(i - 1) = "Suspension PN"
        End If

    Next x
End If
```

Comment: Does calling `MsgBox (ctl)` take the focus away from the form? Try to comment this out.

Comment: `MsgBox(ctl)` was added while I was trying to troubleshoot it, all it does is give the values of the controls that I'm checking through. I added it to see if it was making it just through the first record or if it kept going at all